# Access GET Variable on class instantiation PHP?

Tags: php, class

How can I retrieve GET values inside a PHP Class construct or functions?

Similar subject can be found here which I referred to session values, scope.
[Access Session Variable within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874976/access-session-variable-within-a-class)

Example which doesn't retrieve value, set inside class construct.

```
$this->siteid = $_GET['siteid'];
```

or

```
$this->siteid = $_REQUEST['siteid'];
```

The purpose of the above is to retrieve id for testing params, goal is to hold these inside session, similar problem.

Comment: $_GET is a "superglobal"; it shouldn't make any difference whether it's inside a constructor, function or anything else.  Does the variable exist inside $_GET when called elsewhere?  If so, it will only not exist inside the constructor if you've unset it somewhere else.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: siteid

Comment: @Codex73: this means it is undefined, obviously

Comment: That exact same code works before the class instantiation but doesn't work in the class' constructor?

Comment: @Codex73 Undefined index message its mean there is no name with it, make sure you have a variable called 'siteid' in your request.

Comment: variable is being pass on request ?siteid=35 The problem I believe is the scope which can't be accessed. @Fanis Don't understand your question. @zerkms This is why the question is done as we can't see the GET.

Comment: @Codex73 - This can't be a scope problem since `$_GET` can be accessed anywhere. As Tapos suggested, try `var_dump`ing the `$_GET` before and in the constructor.

Comment: Log or print out the value of `$_GET['siteid']` before you instantiate your class. Does it show "35"? Now inside the class constructor do the same. Does it again show "35"?

Comment: I've printed $_GET['siteid'] before, after and inside construct, all return the correct passed value. The problem I'm having is assigning this value to a class variable, that's where it breaks. The var has been also declared in the class.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!! I find it odd. Will keep trying. Could it be a php setting?

Comment: Everybody comments very helpful, problem solved. It wasn't a problem with scope or global but with class instantiation order, overlapping with others. Again Thanks!@ great community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check what does `var_dump($_REQUEST)`. I think that variable isn't present in `$_GET` variable in that particular page in where you are accessing the class.

Comment: array(1) {
  ["siteid"]=>
  string(2) "86"
}

Comment: I just wrote `<?php
class A {
 var $siteid;
 public function  __construct() {
  $this->siteid = 0;
 }
 public function setSiteId(){
  $this->siteid = $_GET["siteid"];
 }
 public function getSiteId(){
  return $this->siteid;
 }
}
$a = new A();
$a->setSiteId();
var_dump($a->getSiteId());
?>` and this is working fine for me.

Comment: @Tapos Yes that works for your scenario. I have a slight different need which is assigning the request value to an inside object variable. It could be the order I'm calling processes.

Comment: It wasn't a problem with scope or global but with class instantiation order, overlapping with others. Also a ajax request passing a value which included variable.